# converting a number to string in C

Tags: c, string

```c
int n = 10;
char *s;
while (n > 0) {
  s[strlen(s)] = n % 2 + 48;
  n = n / 2;
}
printf("%s", s);
```

I tried to convert a series of 0's and 1's into **string** but, I didn't get the output as expected, eventhough, this logic is correct. What goes wrong here?

Comment: You haven't assigned any memory for your string! Try `char s[50] = "";` instead of `char *s;` (which will reserve 50 characters).

Comment: you mean char s[50] = "" ;

Comment: Use `'0'` instead of `48` — it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use the sprintf() function.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    char result[50]; 
    int n = 10; 
    sprintf(result, "%d", n); 
    printf("The string for the n is %s\n", result); 
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Note that the code in the question is actually trying to produce the binary representation of the value (`1010` for decimal 10, for example).  Unfortunately, `sprintf()` doesn't have a standard 'format as binary' conversion specifier.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sorry, should have read that more carefully

Comment: Me too — the duplicate may not be the best for 'convert integer to string using binary notation'.  I'm working on finding additional questions to make as a duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not disputing the duplicate(s) here but, having just revisited this, I noticed that the OP's code *does* actually create the binary representation of a given `n` - just that it's **backwards**! I found that interesting, at least.

Comment: @AdrianMole — It's always easiest to generate the least significant digit first (`n % base` gives you the least significant digit).  One way around that is to reverse the string after generating the digits.  Another is to recurse on `n / base` (if it is greater than zero) before adding `n % base` to the output.  The OPs code doesn't null terminate the string.  The question doesn't show the output received and explain what's wrong with it, either (nor does it include a newline at the end of the output as it should for comfort).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed! But when I first came across the post (and made my comment), I failed to spot the reversal - and I feel embarrassed that I could have made a cleaner post (answer) and saved time and trouble. That I was, at the time, in an airport lounge between two long flights is no excuse, but may explain my (temporary?) lack of focus!